# What were the first 18 photos Debbie Ocean sent to John Frazier?

Tags: oceans-8

Towards the end of *Ocean’s Eight*, Debbie Ocean texts a photo of a certain very spoilery item to insurance agent John Frazier to enable him to get a search warrant for an intended suspect’s house.

When Frazier opens the text on his iPhone, you can see at the top of his phone screen that it says “19 of 19” (or possibly “13 of 13” or “18 of 18” – bit hard to see the number quite clearly in the half a second it’s visible), which would mean that Debbie had previously texted 12/17/18 photos to Frazier.

The two clearly have some history – at least Frazier has some history with the Ocean family in general – but it doesn’t seem like the type of history that would extend to texting each other memes.

So is there any indication that it’s known what photos Debbie Ocean had previously texted to John Frazier?

Comment: That's not what 13 of 13 means....it just means that it's the last one he has stored in his phone, not that he received 13 from Debbie. Since this is the latest image that would make sense.

Comment: @Paulie_D No, that’s not how viewing photos in texts works on iOS. If you have an iPhone, try opening a photo received in a text and then swipe right/left – it will go through the photos received _in that text thread_ and show ‘X of X’ at the top, counting only photos from that thread. I don’t recall if you actually see the click from the text to the photo, but if it’s stored, that would mean he’d have opened the text, opened the image, saved it, closed the text, opened the Photos app and opened the photo there – which would be a bizarre thing to do.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: It is possible to automate downloads to Photos, and it is possible to configure it as the app handlers for images. Having done IT support for journalists, it was configured this way by default on their company phones since they will generally want to store images they're receiving. It's not unrealistic for insurance agents to have a similar tendency to store received images.

Comment: @Flater Are there? I’ve never seen that, and a quick Google search only gives me a bunch of workarounds that start off saying that it’s _not_ possible to auto-save photos in incoming texts (and then start talking about the auto-save feature introduced in iOS 12 that auto-saves outgoing pictures taken in the Messages app)…